# Problem Exporting Contacts

Tags: export

I'm running Civi 4.6.7 on Joomla 3.4.3 and I'm getting an unknown error anytime I try to export. Please see the link below for a video of the process and what I'm encountering.

http://screencast.com/t/EQZJUI8R

I tried "Select Fields for Import" and used a save field mapping and it exported the data just fine.

I also attempted to export a smaller number of records and did not receive any errors. I enabled debugging and backtrace on our Dev site and this is what it was giving me:

OregonJohn, I tried "Select Fields for Import" and used a save field mapping and it exported the data just fine.

Lesley Evensen, I also attempted to export a smaller number of records and did not receive any errors. I enabled debugging and backtrace on our Dev site and this is what it was giving me:

`#0/mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace() #1internal function: CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error)) #2/mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error)) #3/mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #4 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #5 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...", "DB_Error", TRUE) #6 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1317 ** Query execution was interrupted") #7 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError() #8 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #9 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #10 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #11 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #12 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1192): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...", TRUE) #13 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php(673): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as contact_type,...") #14 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/Form/Select.php(434): CRM_Export_BAO_Export::exportComponents(TRUE, (Array:0), (Array:7), "sort_name asc", NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, "civicrm_task_action_temp_3f2778dfd0b04a5460a46020efe47476_1756", 0, 0, (Array:11), "AND") #15 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Export_Form_Select->postProcess() #16 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(164): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess() #17 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next", "Next") #18 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next") #19 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next") #20 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next") #21 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:4), (Array:0)) #22 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13)) #23 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4)) #24 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(116): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4)) #25 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke() #26 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(392): require_once("/mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/compone...") #27 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(372): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/compone...") #28 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm") #29 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(152): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch() #30 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(252): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute() #31 /mnt/data/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/administrator/index.php(47): JApplicationCms->execute() #32 {main}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try 'Select fields for export' and did you get the same response?

Comment: What is the default download folder for your site, is it writable, can you export fewe records (memberships,addresses, something < 1000 to test), can you turn on debugging, backtrace and re-test?

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of this is that you are hitting performance issues on exporting groups which is appearing as this error.

One way of checking this is
1) upgrade to 4.6.10
2) Swap the codebase for the Fuzion version of 4.6.10 http://dist.fudev.co.nz/by-date/latest/4.6.10.0/ - you can switch between the Core codebase & the Fuzion codebase safely. However, we reverted some changes in Fuzion that added functionality but hurt performance around groups so  testing on our codebase may allow us to rule this in or out as the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Eileen! I'll certainly give this a try. Unfortunately, I'm getting a 404 error when I try to access the link from your post. Please let me know if there is another way to access the link.